# Issue On Passing PHP Value to jQuery Function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Can you please take a look at this code and let me know why I am not able to pass variable value from PHP to jQuery?

```
<?php
$data = "This is For Test";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="test" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    var data = "<?php $data; ?>";
    $("#test").on("click",function(){
     alert(data);
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <script>
        var data = "<?php echo $data; ?>";
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `echo` for `<?php echo $data; ?>`

Answer (score -1):

use

```
<?php echo $data; ?>
```